# "Малышик" или "малышек"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно пишется: *малышик* или *малышек*?

*Господа, давайте предоставим автору право решать, идет ли речь об именительном единственного или родительном множественного. Ответы, как вы понимаете, зависят от этого выбора весьма существенно.*
*b-s*

Comment: Правильно: малышек...

Comment: малыш'ок, -шк'а

Русский орфографический словарь. / Российская академия наук. Ин-т рус. яз. им. В. В. Виноградова. — М.: "Азбуковник". В. В. Лопатин (ответственный редактор), Б. З. Букчина, Н. А. Еськова и др.. 1999.

Comment: Под ударением ок, без ударения ек.

Comment: Да, я тоже нашёл только малышкА какого-то, но это совершенно не соответствует тому, что я слышал. Такое слово (малыш**о**к) первый раз слышу, а слово мал**ы**шик всегда считал, что есть! Странные какие-то словари...

Comment: Да откуда вы все так уверены, что автор имел в виду родительный падеж?!

Comment: Артём, здесь простая вещь. Если слово не фиксируется в словаре, то оно не существует в смысле нормативности написания. У меня нет орфоэпического под рукой, если и там нет, то можете считать, что тут работает только аналогия. Да, при таком образовании уменьшительной формы написание должно быть именно таким. Суффикс -ик. Но вряд ли автор о нем спрашивал. Тут родительный падеж наверняка имеется в виду. Впрочем, можно дождаться автора.

Comment: У Сержа другая ошибка. Он дал правильное написание для родительного падежа, но опять не то правило привел. Для написания суффиксов -ик/-ек работает правило о беглой правило о беглой гласной. Знаменитый "Ключик-замочек": ключика - замочка. В первом случае нет беглой, поэтому "ключ**и**к", во втором - беглая, поэтому замоч**е**к. Отсюда "Малы'ш**и**к" (ударение на ы), т.к. р.п. - "малышика", как ключика.

Comment: Да, я тоже за то, чтобы дождаться автора, если он, конечно, придёт и напишет что-то. Мне кажется, что он про именительный падеж спросил потому, что в родительном написать "шик" сложнее. Может ошибиться малограмотный человек, но если подумает, то вряд ли допустит И.

Comment: Понимаете, "грамотный" не стал бы задавать подобный вопрос в принципе. А если уж пришла нужда, оговорил бы, о каком падеже речь. Нет, тут скорее всего - для школьных нужд. Начальные классы. Поэтому вернее всего - родительный множественного от "малышка"

Comment: Возможно, будем надеяться, что автор прояснит, что имел в виду. Кстати, behemothus, мне очень интересно, что вы думаете по поводу моего ответа про "думаю, что точно..."!

Comment: Пока Вы надеялись, господин Shampar уже все решил за автора. ))) Скорее всего мы так уже ничего и не узнаем. ))) *Пропал калабуховский дом.* (С)

Answer (score 2):

Почему-то ни в каком словаре не нашёл слово *мал**ы**шик*, но если оно существует, то пишется через И, а *малыш**е**к* — это род. падеж мн. ч. от слова "малышка" (девочка, но, как говорит Ожегов, и не только).

> В существительных  с суффиксами *ик, ек* при изменении слова
>
> - если  в нём  сохраняется и, пиши суффикс *ик:*  мячик – мячики
> - если гласный звук исчезает, пиши суффикс *ек:*  платочек – платочка

[Источник](http://russkiy-na-5.ru/rules/51)

Comment: Артем, упомянутые вами суффиксы имеют место в именительном падеже, а в нашем примере речь идет о родительном падеже.

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что о родительном речь?!

Comment: Тёма, мне так "малышик" понравился, что я его загуглила; попробуй "такой хорошенький малышик"! )))

Comment: Загуглил, и что?)

Comment: Я тоже не поленился, погуглил. Результаты даже меня удивили. Да, скорее это "малышок" надо признать отклонением от статистической нормы.

Answer (score 1):

Я тоже слышала и нередко употребляю слово "малышик" в именительном падеже как уменьшительное, ласкательное от "малыш". Если оно не входит в словари сегодня, то может войти со временем по мере распространения. Слово бытовое и употребляется в таких ситуациях, где не важна формальная грамотность. Мы же видим, как меняется язык и как признаются слова, которые ещё недавно казались невозможными. А "малышек" - родительный падеж множественного числа женского рода.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: малышек.
Малышка, -и; ***мн. род. -шек,*** дат. -шкам; м. и ж. =Малыш

Русский орфографический словарь Российской академии наук.
Отв. ред. В. В. Лопатин.

Comment: Серж, так в чём же дело?! Слова "мал**ы**шик" (на Ы, если плохо видно) не существует? Но я же его сто раз слышал!

Comment: Артем, если слышали, не значит, что так правильно. Во всех словарвх зафиксировано: малышОк. Прочитайте, в конце концов,  о суффиксах ок-ек.

Comment: Автора интересовало, как пишется, я и написал,указав словарь в качестве доказательства. Вы привели правило (кстати неправильное!),  Если автора интересовало правило - давно выучил бы.

Comment: Смешно! Никак не угомонитесь? Вот видите, вы считаете, что Вы самый умный, никогда недооцениваете других, даже профессоров. Зачем Вы продолжаете писать? Если вы были бы уверенным носителем, вы бы не стали утверждать, что  в слове ***малышок*** окончание ик.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, здесь речь идет все-таки о родительном падеже слова "малышка": *"у нас нет малышек, все взрослые"*. Написание через Е диктуется не словарями, но общим правилом. ***Малышки - малышек*** (беглая гласная, всегда Е). "Ик" возможно только в отдельных словах, в основном - заимствованных, имеющих в именительном "-ики": (красивые) базилики - (красивых) базилик, (красные) гвоздики - красных гвоздик и т.д. Место ударения здесь не существенно.

В отношении гипотетического слова "(один) малышик". Здесь И, думается. У Сержа другая ошибка. Он дал правильное написание для родительного падежа "малышек", но опять не то правило привел. Для написания суффиксов -ик/-ек работает правило о беглой гласной. Знаменитый "Ключик-замочек": ключика - замочка. В первом случае нет беглой, поэтому "ключ**и**к", во втором - беглая, поэтому замоч**е**к. Отсюда "Малы'ш**и**к" (ударение на ы), т.к. р.п. - "малышика", как ключика.

Пока суть да дело, убедился в реальности существования "малышика". А с ней и в неочевидности и неоднозначности формулировки вопроса, трактуемой как относящейся к родительному падежу...

Comment: Вы - это не все подряд. ))) Минусы я ставлю очень редко и не по личным предпочтениям а за конкретные ответы, за те обычно, в которых просматривается воинственная невежественность или нежелание разобраться.

Comment: А... это "позиция" у вас такая? Так вы предупреждайте в другой раз, что в позицию встали, я вас и трогать не буду. Серж, я понимаю, что у вас русский не родной, но посмотрите в словаре, что означает слово "позиция". Если найдете хоть что-то, что позволит мне заключить, что приведенное вами **правило** (которое проходят едва ли не в начальной школе) можно назвать позицией, я извинюсь. Иначе, простите, я никогда не поверю, что вы понимаете смысл вами написанного.

Comment: Если у Вас русский родной, я вам русским языком и говорю. Во-первых, прекратите переходить на личности. Во-вторых, не приписывайте мне собственных грехов. Если Вы не знаете правила, которое вы же и приводите, называя его "позицией", то это не моя вина.

Comment: (+) "это вам непонятно элементарных вещей" - Если это "родной русский", то я точно мать Тереза.

Comment: Знаете, правила не знаете Вы. Это видно в вашем ответе. Слова ''малышИК не зафиксировано не в одном орфографическом словаре. Но как всегда, не зная нормально правил, Вы любите спорить. здесь пишется суффикс ок , потому что на него падает ударение. Этот суффикс бывает в ударной позиции.

Comment: *Это видно в вашем ответе. Слова ''малышИК не зафиксировано не в одном орфографическом словаре.* - А при чем тут знание правил? Это первое. Второе. Вы все-таки плохо понимаете русский  язык. Я сам и сказал, что оно не зафиксировано. Но для настоящего носителя русского языка не составит труда просклонять любое слово, даже только что выдуманное. Или там фамилию диковинную. Вот мой ник просклоняете? Так и тут. Если Вы владеете элементарной речевой культурой, то ни в словарь не полезете, ни возмущаться не будете, если там не найдете.  Именно потому, что это правило, а не словарная случайность.

Comment: Это Вы не владеете элементарной речевой культурой. Это видно из Ваших. Наш сор заходит в тупик, потому что мы говорим о разных вещах, и вы сами себе противоречите. Это оттого, что вы никогда нормально не читаете чужие ответы и сразу видите (потому что Вам это нравится!) ошибку. И начинаете спорить! Прежде чем говорить о правилах, почитайте их. Словарь, кстати, будет это Вам известно, фиксирует правила!

Comment: Вы сказали, что оно не зафиксировано, но тем не менее утверждаете, что оно существует! Это опять говорит о том, что Вы не знаете правил. Если бы существовала эта форма слова, то и в словарь попала бы!

Comment: Больше не желаю с вами спорить! Вы признаете только свои правильными!

Comment: *Но как всегда, не зная нормально правил, Вы любите спорить. здесь пишется суффикс ок , потому что на него падает ударение. Этот суффикс бывает в ударной позиции.* - Серж, это полнейшая ерунда. Вы совсем уже оторвались от предмета. 1) В предпологаемом слове "малышик" ударение на Ы. Все остальное - ффтопку 2) Правило Ваше мало того, что не имеет отношения к нашему случаю, так Вы еще и неверно его формулируете. Оно касается только правописания после шипящих для случая фонетического О. Слова "разведчик", "боярышник" или там "котик" никогда через е писаться не будут вопреки Вашей формулировке.

Comment: *Больше не желаю с вами спорить! Вы признаете только свои правильными!* - ну посмотрим, сколько Вы продержитесь.)))

Comment: *Вы сказали, что оно не зафиксировано, но тем не менее утверждаете, что оно существует! * - Цитату пожалуйста, где я такое сказал.  Впрочем, на свете есть много слов, которые не зафиксированы в словарях. Да и Вы наверняка не все словари читали. Я вам пример приводил. Кто скажет, что имя собственное это не слово? Вы все фамилии можете найти в словарях?